# Half siblings or double cousins?

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings, double-cousins

**MB**= my brother (1/2 sibling)
**MC**=cousin (our mother's sister's daughter given up for adoption-no longer married to **SS**)
**DC**=cousin to both of us but either 1/2 sibling to my brother or double cousin)
**AS**= possible father to **MB**
**SS**=possible father to both **MB** & **DC**

My brother and I have confirmed that we are half siblings 1761 cM w/75 segments. My mother denied this but family members were always telling us "cryptic" stories. All the parents in this are deceased. There was always the likelihood that my brother's father was my aunt's husband's brother (brother-in-law) **AS**.   Then after our mother died, my aunt said she thought **AS** might not have been in country at the time but our mother was staying at her house (she was in hospital). So this brought up the great possibility that her husband **SS** would be his **MB** father. So now we have found the daughter given up for adoption & both  females have done the DNA test.

**MB** shares 1761 cM w/75 segments with me, 1529 cM w/67 segments with **DC**. I share 840 cM w/42 segments w/**DC**. I do not know what he shares w/**MC** yet. DC shares 1826 cM w/61 segments with **MC** I share 969 cM w/47 segments with **MC**. Without having others to test, is this just too close to say whether **MB** & **DC** are 1/2 siblings or double cousins?